# How to reduce Microsoft HoloLens Live preview latency

Tags: c#, http, video, hololens

I am currently working with the Microsoft Hololens. It provides a Webinterface where you can see a live video in 720p at 30 fps including holograms and audio. But the video stream has a 2-3 seconds delay. Even if I reduce everything at it's minimum, without audio and holos, it barely changes nothing. The hololens uses a http restful API. I've tested it with vlc player and a selfmade C# app using the windows media player. Still no changes. Any ideas?

Comment: A stable internet connection reduced it to 1.5 seconds delay for me. But i haven't been able to make it any faster than that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need something like 200ms or even less.

Comment: same problem here. Even with the usb connection and talking to the service at 127.0.0.1 involves the same latency, so I assume the delay occurs at the stream packaging stage and not in the network.

Comment: You have to use the samples from Microsoft, there is one for unity and one for UWP. Try looking for low latency sample.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce lag for live video stream from a hololens, make sure the wireless network the hololens is connected to is capable of high speed transfer.  We use one of these TP Link Routers http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5506_AD7200.html which works very well for doing demo presentations and reduces the latency to almost real time.

Comment: it's more than a second of delay even if I connect it with a usb cable to the host computer and access the stream with the localhost adress